# API Not Searching Food Database When Clicking The Search Button get error Permission denied

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

Hey Guys I'm working on a calorie app where the user clicks the search button and it supposed to retrieve information from the USDA Food Composition Databases API. For some reason it doesnt do anything and I noticed I get an error in the Logcat.

Im new to Android and to API. Thanks again in advance..

**logcat :**

[Here is the logcat Error I'm Getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRMEh.png)

**AddEntry.java**

```
  public class AddEntry extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener  {

  EditText FoodET,CalorieET;


  ImageButton Savebtn, Cancelbtn;
   Button searchbutton;

  String foodET,calorieET;


    //database
   private DatabaseHandler dba;


    public AddEntry() {
    // Required empty public constructor
   }


  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_entry, container, 
    false);
   Savebtn = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.SaveBtn);
    Savebtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    Savebtn.setOnClickListener(this);


    searchbutton = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.SearchButton);
    searchbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

    Cancelbtn = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.CancelBtn);
    Cancelbtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    Cancelbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    return myView;


   }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    FoodET= (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.foodEditText);

    FoodET.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

    CalorieET=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.caloriesEditText);
    CalorieET.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

    foodET = ((EditText) 
    view.findViewById(R.id.foodEditText)).getText().toString();
    calorieET = ((EditText) 
    view.findViewById(R.id.caloriesEditText)).getText().toString();

     }





   public void saveDataToDB (){

    Food food = new Food();

    String FoodName = FoodET.getText().toString().trim();
    String calString = CalorieET.getText().toString().trim();

    //convert the claories numbers to text

    if (!calString.equals("")) {

        int cal = Integer.parseInt(calString);


        food.setFoodName(FoodName);
        food.setCalories(cal);

        //call addFood method from the DatabaseHandler
        dba.addFood(food);
        dba.close();


        //clear the editTexts
        FoodET.setText("");
        CalorieET.setText("");

        //take the user to the next screen
        //

        ((appMain) getActivity()).loadSelection(0);
        ;
    }
    else
    {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter information", 
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case  R.id.SearchButton:
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)

            getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow( 
            getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);


            FoodSearch search = new FoodSearch(foodET,CalorieET );

            search.execute();
            break;

        case R.id.SaveBtn:


            foodET = FoodET.getText().toString();
            calorieET=CalorieET.getText().toString();

            if (FoodET.getText().toString().equals(null) || 
            CalorieET.getText().toString().equals(null)||   
           CalorieET.getText().toString().equals("")){

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter information", 
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            ((appMain) getActivity()).loadSelection(0);


            break;


        case R.id.CancelBtn:

           // EditText descriptionET= 
         (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.foodEditText);
          //descriptionET.setText("");


            //EditText calorieET= 
           (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.caloriesEditText);

            //calorieET.setText("");

            ((appMain) getActivity()).loadSelection(0);

            break;
         }
               }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

          }

          @Override
          public void onDetach() {
          super.onDetach();
           }




   private class FoodSearch extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    String food;
    EditText calories;

    FoodSearch(String food, EditText calories){
        this.food = food;
        this.calories = calories;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            food = food.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
            URL url = new URL("http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/? 
         format=JSON&q=" + food 
        +"&max=1&offset=0&sort=r&api_
         key=2PmoCzLAhkNUeJcwq2VfOaSNY66UgFVDEcco2qMP");
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)
                    url.openConnection();
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
               InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                String result = stringBuilder.toString();
                if(result.contains("zero results")) {
                    String s = "empty";
                    return s;
                }
                JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new
                        JSONTokener(result).nextValue();
                JSONObject list = object.getJSONObject("list");
                JSONArray items = list.getJSONArray("item");
                String item = items.get(0).toString();
                int i = item.indexOf("ndbno\":\"") + 8;
                int f = item.indexOf("\"", i);
                String ndbno = item.substring(i,f);
                Log.d("DEBUG", ndbno);

                URL url2 = new URL("http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/reports/?
                 ndbno="+ ndbno +"&type=b&format=JSON&api_
                key=2PmoCzLAhkNUeJcwq2VfOaSNY66UgFVDEcco2qMP");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection2 = (HttpURLConnection)
                        url2.openConnection();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader2 = new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(urlConnection2.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder2 = new StringBuilder();
                String line2;
                while ((line2 = bufferedReader2.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder2.append(line2).append("\n");
                }
                bufferedReader2.close();
                String res = stringBuilder2.toString();
                int index = res.indexOf("\"unit\": \"kcal\",") + 46;
                int index2 = res.indexOf("\"", index);
                String calories = res.substring(index,index2);
                urlConnection2.disconnect();
                return calories;
            }
            finally{
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
            String s = "empty";
            return s;
        }
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        if(!response.isEmpty() && !response.equals("empty")) {
            calories.setText(response);
        } else {
            AlertDialog foodNotFound = new
                    AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
            foodNotFound.setTitle("Error");
            foodNotFound.setMessage("Food not found :(");
            foodNotFound.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int  
                       which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                  }
               }
            }

          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can call the Async task within the same class and SHow alert dialog in the onPost execute section

```
public class AddEntry extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText DescriptionET,CalorieET; ImageButton Savebtn, Cancelbtn; Button searchbutton; String description , calorieAmt; //database 
private DatabaseHandler dba;

public AddEntry() { 
    // Required empty public constructor 
}

@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) { // Inflate the layout for this fragment View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_entry, container, false);
       Savebtn = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.SaveBtn);
       Savebtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
       Savebtn.setOnClickListener(this);


       searchbutton = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.SearchButton);
       searchbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

       Cancelbtn = (ImageButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.CancelBtn);
       Cancelbtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
       Cancelbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
       return myView;

        }


     @Override
     public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    DescriptionET= (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.foodEditText);

    DescriptionET.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

    CalorieET=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.caloriesEditText);
    CalorieET.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);


    //save to database:



    }
       public void saveDataToDB (){

       Food food = new Food();

    String name = DescriptionET.getText().toString().trim();
    String calString = CalorieET.getText().toString().trim();

    //convert the claories numbers to text

    if (!calString.equals("")) {

        int cal = Integer.parseInt(calString);


        food.setFoodName(name);
        food.setCalories(cal);

        //call addFood method from the DatabaseHandler
        dba.addFood(food);
        dba.close();


        //clear the editTexts
        DescriptionET.setText("");
        CalorieET.setText("");

        //take the user to the next screen
        //

        ((appMain) getActivity()).loadSelection(0);
        ;
        }
        else
        {

           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter information",   
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

      }

             @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
          switch (v.getId()) {
        case  R.id.SearchButton:
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)

            getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);


            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(  

            getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

            FoodSearch search = new FoodSearch(description,CalorieET);
            search.execute();


            break;

        case R.id.SaveBtn:


            description = DescriptionET.getText().toString();
            calorieAmt=CalorieET.getText().toString();

            if (DescriptionET.getText().toString().equals(null) || 
           CalorieET.getText().toString().equals(null)|| 
          CalorieET.getText().toString().equals("")){

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter information", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            ((appMain) getActivity()).loadSelection(0);


            break;


        case R.id.CancelBtn:


           // EditText descriptionET= 
         (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.foodEditText);
          //descriptionET.setText("");


            //EditText calorieET= 
         (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.caloriesEditText);
            //calorieET.setText("");

            ((appMain) getActivity()).loadSelection(0);

            break;
             }
            }


             @Override
             public void onDestroy() {
             super.onDestroy();

              }

          @Override
          public void onDetach() {
          super.onDetach();
         }

      }
    private class FoodSearch extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
        String food;
        EditText calories;

        FoodSearch(String food, EditText calories){
           this.food = food;
           this.calories = calories;
         }

         @Override
         protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
         try {
            food = food.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
            URL url = new URL("http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?
            format=JSON&q=" + food +"&max=1&offset=0&sort=r&api_key=2PmoCzLAhkNUeJcwq2VfOaSNY66UgFVDEcco2qMP");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) 
          url.openConnection();
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
                InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                String result = stringBuilder.toString();
                if(result.contains("zero results")) {
                    String s = "empty";
                    return s;
                }
                JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new 
                JSONTokener(result).nextValue();
                JSONObject list = object.getJSONObject("list");
                JSONArray items = list.getJSONArray("item");
                String item = items.get(0).toString();
                int i = item.indexOf("ndbno\":\"") + 8;
                int f = item.indexOf("\"", i);
                String ndbno = item.substring(i,f);
                Log.d("DEBUG", ndbno);

                URL url2 = new URL("http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/reports/?ndbno="+ ndbno +"&type=b&format=JSON&api_key=2PmoCzLAhkNUeJcwq2VfOaSNY66UgFVDEcco2qMP");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection2 = (HttpURLConnection) 
                url2.openConnection();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader2 = new BufferedReader(new 
                InputStreamReader(urlConnection2.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder2 = new StringBuilder();
                String line2;
                while ((line2 = bufferedReader2.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder2.append(line2).append("\n");
                }
                bufferedReader2.close();
                String res = stringBuilder2.toString();
                int index = res.indexOf("\"unit\": \"kcal\",") + 46;
                int index2 = res.indexOf("\"", index);
                String calories = res.substring(index,index2);
                urlConnection2.disconnect();
                return calories;
            }
        finally{
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
        String s = "empty";
        return s;
        }
     }
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        if(!response.isEmpty() && !response.equals("empty")) {
            calories.setText(response);
        } else {
            AlertDialog foodNotFound = new 
            AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
            foodNotFound.setTitle("Error");
            foodNotFound.setMessage("Food not found :(");
            foodNotFound.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried following the code you provided  and placed it within the class but when doing so

this line of code is red 
("http://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/search/?
                        format=JSON&q=" + food +"&max=1&offset=0&sort=r&api_key=2PmoCzLAhkNUeJcwq2VfOaSNY66UgFVDEcco2qMP");

and urlConnection

Comment: sorry it was this line getting an error getInputStream says cannot get method